# iPad distorting UIImageView on device only

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a .png image that is 1024 pixels wide, and 120 pixels high, and is meant to span the bottom of the iPad screen (in landscape mode).[image].

I intentionally have the image view at the same size as the image resolution, so that no resizing is performed, and there is a 1:1 ratio between the image pixels, and screen pixels. On the iPad simulator at 100% zoom, the png appear exactly the same, as it should. When I test it on my iPad 1, the image becomes distorted, like iOS is trying to resample the image. Below is a screenshot taken from the device[image].

If I output the UIImageView bounds, I get the expected width and height. Any ideas on why this is happening, and why the distortion doesn't appear on the simulator?

EDIT: Code used to insert ImageView:

```
tile = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tile.png"]];
[tile setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 648, tile.bounds.size.width, tile.bounds.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:tile];
```

I got the same results using both IB and programmed.

EDIT: Output of `po [[(id)UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`

```
<UIWindow: 0x13f200; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x127df0>>
| <UIView: 0x14fd40; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x14ffe0>>
|    | <UIImageView: 0x14f900; frame = (0 648; 1024 120); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x14f940>>
|    | <UIImageView: 0x14e210; frame = (125 666; 774 102); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x14daa0>>
```

Comment: To see the distortion clearly, it might be better to go to the the linked images directly: [png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Ibd.png), [iPad screen capture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fl6Ti.png)

Comment: Can you show the code that places the image

Comment: Pause the app in gdb and paste in the output of this command: `po [[(id)UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.

Comment: Currently I have it added using IB, but I added the code I had before...

Comment: @robmayoff I added that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what is causing the distortion, but if I trim the image size from 1024x120 to 1023x120, I don't get any distortion, only a slight 1px gap on the right.

Comment: I'll wait another day or so before marking this as the correct answer, is case someone knows exactly whats going on here.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK an UIImageView just draws the image and like all drawing methods in CoreGraphics the coordinates are not a pixel index, but points around which each dot is drawn. If you draw a horizontal line then half of it is gets added to the pixels above, half of it to the pixels below.

You only see this in your example because you are trying to use this pattern that has so fine features and so the anti-aliasing has the effect you describe.

If you want to show the graphics true to the original, then you will have to draw it yourself and disable anti-aliasing. Or possibly by adding a CALayer as sublayer with the contents property set to be the image.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but I used similar 'detailed' images which don't show this effect. To test it out, I took a chunk (about 1/3) of the image above, and displayed it, and it comes out fine. I was thinking that maybe there is some image compression going on behind the scenes for images over a certain size?